# Sitecore XSL cache

Tags: sitecore

Hi can any tell me how we can clear the XSL cache in Sitecore 6.2. When i publish my XSLT code files from staging to production I have a cache problem because of which the content or the images which are rendered using this xslt code are not rendered even when I havent opened a particular URL before. When i clear the cache using \sitecore\admin\cache.aspx some time later after that I can see the content displaying. But i cannot suggest my customers to clear the cache when ever a new file is published to production. Is there any way where we can clear the caching done by XSLT files. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "a new file is published to production". Is it a file that is in Sitecore and is published from there? Are you using any form of staging or have several webserves? Are you using more than one <sites> and the cache isn't getting cleared on one of them?

Answer (score 1):

You are already doing the right thing: after publishing the XSLT files from staging to production, you need to clear the cache with the `\sitecore\admin\cache.aspx` page.
This is about server-side cache so it will clear the cache for all your visitors.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use XSL renderings very often but from what I can see, the `XslWatcher` should clear the XSL cache when XSL files are added, removed, changed, or renamed. Can you confirm that you have the following configuration elements in your Web.config?

In system.web or system.webServer HTTP modules:

```
<add type="Sitecore.IO.XslWatcher, Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreXslWatcher" />
```

In /sitecore/watchers:

```
  <xsl>
    <folder>/</folder>
    <filter>*.xslt</filter>
  </xsl>
```