# Clear Sitecore XSLT Cache

Tags: xslt, caching, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

Question: Can anybody let me know on how to clear a sitecore xslt cache?

Problem : We have implemented Main Navigation and Footer Navigation from the same items in Sitecore.We had a urgent requirement to remove an item from Main Navigation and Footer.

We removed the item from Main Navigation by unpublishing the item in sitecore.However footer is implemented using XSLT as below :

```
<sc:xslfile visible="true" runat="server" id="xslFooter" cacheable="true" varybydata="true" />
```

Now even though the item is unpublished,it is still visible in the footer of the site and my guess is, it is because of XSLT cache.So can you please tell me on how this can be done.

Note:I can't write any code for this now as I need to remove immediately from live site.Also I can't clear using admin tool as it clears cache for all users?

So any solution for this?

Thanks,
Suhas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to /sitecore/admin/cache.aspx you will be able to clear the cache, but I assume this is the admin tool you don't want to use.

You say that you don't want to clear the cache for all users, but I can't see a way around this because the cache is not user/visitor specific.

If acceptable, you can also clear the XSL cache by renaming/updaing/adding a file in the XSL folder.

The issue has been discussed here:
[Sitecore XSL cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137461/sitecore-xsl-cache)

Comment: :Thanks for the reply.I saw this morning that the item disappeared  without me doing anything .But can you tell me what is the TTL  for this cache?

Comment: I think it lasts until an XSL file is changed/added/removed or the application restarts.